# After Syncing my Invoice and Sales receipts are being lost from IDS and QB Desktop both

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

> I have created a invoice onto IDS with success message and I also
>   getting invoice details from IDS untill I did Syncing from QB Desktop
>   Sync Manager.

I am not getting any error while syncing also.I have created few invoices in QBDesktop with same process sometimes.

> I am unable to find out the reason why data(invoice/sales receipt)
>   being lost??

I also have a question that :
If I created a customer/item with name ABC in QBDesktop and then same name on IDS before Syncing. It's created successfully on IDS and also getting from IDS,
but when I do sync from Sync Manager , customer/item lost from IDS. ??

I also want to know that how can we get and manage SyncStaus to resolve conflicts?
Ref.

> http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com...

Is there any workaround for these issues?

Answer (score 3):

Please see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863355/payment-not-being-created#answer-14863873) regarding objects in error state and how to resolve them.